# MySql report grouped by location and hour of day

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a mysql table where each entry contains among other, a location string and a datetime field.

I would like to build a mysql query that generates a report with the count(items) grouped by hour of day (on the rows) and the locations (on the columns).

So far I'm manually generating reports grouped by location and I have a WHERE clause where I iterate over each hour of day (24 in number). This is too cumbersome and I would like to do it automatically.

*EDIT*

This is the query i'm now trying to use based on the answer from fxzuz

```
SELECT locations.locationName, DATE_FORMAT(  '%Y-%m-%d %H', entries.CreatedOn ) , COUNT( pk_entry ) 
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.computerName = entries.location
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(  '%Y-%m-%d %H', entries.CreatedOn )
```

Answer (score 2):

What's about mysql function DATE_FORMAT?

```
SELECT location, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), COUNT(id) FROM table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-%d %H', datetime);
```

Comment: it's not working.  I've edited my post to display the sql query i'm using

Comment: The arguments are in the wrong order: it should be `DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H')`. +1 anyway.